# JLabel not showing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, paintcomponent

I'm in the process of finishing up a game and I've reached a point that has made me extremely frustrated.  It's probably a simple fix and something I'm overlooking, so maybe you guys can help me out.  I'm trying to get a series of 5 JLabels to show up on screen with the 5 high scores from the game.  However, it keeps showing up with the background and no labels.  The following is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EndPanel extends JPanel{

   GameGUI gui;
   JLabel[] array;

   public EndPanel(GameGUI gui) {
       super();
       this.gui = gui;
       array = new JLabel[5];
       for(JLabel i : array) {
          i = new JLabel("");
          i.setVisible(true);
          this.add(i);
       }
       int i = 0;
       for(HighScore h: gui.getGameDriver().getHighScores()) {
          System.out.println(gui.getGameDriver().getHighScores());
          array[i].setText(h.toString());
          i++;
       }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       super.paint(g);
       g.drawImage(gui.images.get(32), 0, 0, this);
       g.drawImage(gui.images.get(31), 112, 100, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

The initialization of the array is strongly suspicious.
Instead of:

```
   for(JLabel i : array) {
      i = new JLabel("");
      i.setVisible(true);
      this.add(i);
   }
```

try:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = new JLabel("");
      array[i].setVisible(true);
      add(array[i]);
   }
```

Untested as your code cannot be compiled.

[EDIT]
Actually, you don't need to create an array of JLabel since you throw them out (array goes out of scope at the end of the method). You can create the labels on the fly:

```
   for (HighScore h : gui.getGameDriver().getHighScores()) {
      System.out.println(gui.getGameDriver().getHighScores());
      JLabel label = new JLabel(h.toString());
      add(label);
   }
```

You still need to set the position of these labels, with a layout manager or by absolute position.

Comment: this is exactly what i thought. and i think it is the cause. +1.

Comment: Then follow the advice of AlexR and set the position of your JLabels, either manually (absolute layout...) or via a layout manager (GridLayout for example). The advice of Abu is good too: you should set the text of the label at creation time, otherwise they might have a size of 0, if you don't refresh the layout.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `for each` loop try using regular `for` loop, like this:

```
JLabel [] label = new JLabel[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        label[i] = new JLabel("Label number: " +i);
        panel.add(label[i]);
    }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not use layout manager you have set the label position and size yourself. Otherwise I guess all your labels have size=0 and are positioned at point 0,0.

BTW, do you have a special reason not to use layout manager or you just not aware on it?

Comment: I've used it on all my other panels in the game but I just didn't feel as if it was necessary this time.  I do remember the one panel I didn't use a layout and I had to set size and position though otherwise it didn't show up.  Let me try this out.

Comment: I tried to do a borderlayout instead and use the above for loop like they were saying but it still doesn't work.  Le sigh.

Comment: *"tried to do a borderlayout"* Try a `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout` first.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the `Jlabel` initialization code inside the loop of high score :

```
   int i = 0;
   for(HighScore h: gui.getGameDriver().getHighScores()) {
      System.out.println(gui.getGameDriver().getHighScores());
      array[i] = new JLabel(h.toString());
      this.add(array[i]);
      i++;
   }
```